# Translation help: powers of the seven great men of the city

Tags: commentaries, translation, politics-government, responsa

I'm struggling with a particular part of the reasoning of the Mahari ben-Lev in [responsum 2:72](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1388&pgnum=222), in which he addresses whether or not the טובי העיר have the power to make a rule banning townsfolk from moving to other cities.

The bit with which I'm struggling quotes [the Ran's commentary on Masechet Megillah](https://www.sefaria.org/Ran_on_Megillah.7b.2?vhe=Vilna_Edition&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), which addresses a situation where the טובי העיר are given a vague instruction to look after the community's affairs, then they decide to sell the synagogue, even though the townsfolk would never have imagined they would do such a thing. The Ran, if I understand him correctly, says that this still falls within the authority of the טובי העיר and the sale is valid.

After quoting the Ran, the Mahari ben-Lev says:

> ואי בהאי מילתא הוה אסיק אדעתין דלא נתנו רשות לשבעה טובי העיר כשמנום
> בנדון דידן דעדיף טפי וטפי ודאי אית לן למימר דלא נתנו להם רשות ועל
> כיוצא בזה ואפילו במילתא דאיכא רווחא להאי ופסידא להאי איכא למימר דלא
> עלה על דעתם כי היכי דאין הרוב ושבעה טובי העיר יכולין לכוף את המיעוט
> בכיוצא בזה גם כן אפילו אם מנום עליהם לא מנום אלא לדברים שהוא רגילות
> לגזור בענייני המנהגים התקנות ומיגדר מילתא וכיוצא בזה אבל שיתן אדם
> הבחירה ביד שבעה טובי העיר שיכופו אותו לדור באותה המדינה ולא ללכת לעיר
> אחרת הוא דבר שלא עלה על דעת אדם ואם נתנו להם רשות לגזור עליהם היינו
> בהיותם בני עירם אבל לא שיגזרו עליהם שיהיו אנשי עירם ולא אנשי עיר אחרת

His ultimate conclusion is that the טובי העיר do not have the power to ban townsfolk from moving elsewhere, because the townsfolk never intended to give their leaders such a sweeping power. In the bit that's troubling me, I think the Mahari ben-Lev is explaining why this case is different from the Ran's case (where the fact that the townsfolk never intended to let their leaders sell the synagogue was of no relevance, and the synagogue could be sold regardless). But I don't understand the distinction being made.

If anyone can help me with a translation and/ or explanation, it would be much appreciated!

If it's helpful, here is a footnote to this bit in a modern edition of the Mahari ben-Lev:

[image]

Comment: The point is that they only have power over members of their own city, and therefore they cannot stop someone from leaving, being that the moment one decide to leave, he is no longer a member of that city, and is therefore no longer under their jurisdiction

Comment: @User123 That can’t be why he keeps referring to לא עלה על דעתם.

Comment: What that means is that they never accepted that KIND of authority - not just that specific rule, but anything in that category.

Comment: @User123 Hmmm… I wonder if you could help with an actual translation because while what you’ve said makes sense in abstracto, I’m struggling to identify it in the actual text.

Comment: I’ve bountied this one 

Answer (score 0):

I'll translate from "ואפילו במילתא דאיכא":

> And even a thing that one benefits and another loses out, we can say that they hadn't thought of this, just like the majority with the 7 טובי העיר can't force the minority in something like this. So too, even when they appointed them (טובי העיר) upon themselves, they were only appointed for things that it is normal to decree; for (deciding) traditions, for making edicts, and for creating fences and the like. However, that a man should give the choice to טובי העיר to force him to live in that country (area) and not to leave the city, this is not something that people think of (or: this is inconceivable), and although they gave them the power to make decrees about them, this is only so long as they are members of the city, but not that it be decreed upon them that they must be members of this city and not another!

Or in short, as User123 said in the comments, if טובי העיר sell the shul it's a good sale, because טובי העיר have the ability to decree things thay have to do with the running of the city. However no one ever thought of giving טובי העיר the ability to make 'meta-decrees' about whether one is allowed to *leave* the city.